# Android - How to change the attributes of multiple child views

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout with a lot of textViews and my application can change its theme according to user's preference. How to change all of the textView's textColor and font type attribute in this particular LinearLayout? I cannot use

```
<style name="Theme1" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/theme1TextStyle/item>
</style>
```

in the styles.xml file because I have other textViews in another layout which need different font color and font type. The only way that I can think of is to declare a custom attribute (customTextViewStyle) myself and use it in every textViews (by inserting style="?attr/customTextViewStyle") in that LinearLayout and do the following in styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme1" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:customTextViewStyle">@style/theme1TextStyle/item>
</style>
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? My objective is to make this code readable and easy to modify.

Comment: refer below url.. http://mrbool.com/how-to-change-the-layout-theme-of-an-android-application/25837

Answer (score 1):

make these styles in the `styles.xml`, you can see the working example which is uploaded on [github](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/activities/list/first/TestTextViewActivity.java)

```
<style name="TestOne">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00aa22</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
</style>

<style name="TestTwo">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00aacc</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>

<style name="TestThree">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ddaa00</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed</item>
</style>

<style name="TestFour">
    <item name="android:textColor">#bbaa00</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-thin</item>
</style>

<style name="TestFive">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00aabb</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
</style>
```

and these can be used like this to a `textView`

```
textView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(),R.style.TestOne);
```

I have written an example which you can check

```
public class TestTextViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;

    int[] id = {R.style.TestOne, R.style.TestTwo, R.style.TestThree, R.style.TestFour, R.style.TestFive};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_text_view);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_custom_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        initializeUI();
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TestTextViewActivity_textView);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TestTextViewActivity_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int count = (new Random()).nextInt(6);
                textView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(),id[count]);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

> Output

[image]

Comment: Will changing the style of the text through programming rather than the xml file make the code easier to read and modify? (PS: Thank you for your effort, after I have accumulated enough rep, I will come and upvote your answer ;))

Comment: it depends on you how you code to make code flexible, as you wanted to only some textviews to be changed, so I coded something I thought you wanted. but there is always something to improve...